# Two files that are binary identical, yet exhibit different behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm posting with tags asp.net and excel because that is the origination of my problem, but I'm not really sure this is the right place - ultimately, my problem is that I have two files (served by an ASP.Net application) which are identical based on a binary file compare using

```
fc /B A.xls B.xls
```

However, they exhibit different behavior: the first one opens fine in Excel; the second one does not. I conclude, then, that there is something different about the files beyond what the FC utility checks.

I have tried sending these two files to a friend to ask for his help, but discovered that when I do so, the problem file gets "fixed". In fact, if I do just about anything with this file, it gets "fixed". By fixed, I mean that it then opens fine in Excel. For example, if I zip it, then extract it from the zip, it is fine. If I open in Notepad++ and "Save As", it is fine. Same with Wordpad. Using plain old Notepad does NOT fix it.

So, obviously, there is some difference about these two files that I am missing.

I'm not sure if I will have any luck asking people to visit a random website, but if you want to see an example of the behavior, I have created a minimal page to duplicate the problem at http://rodj.me/ExcelTest

Click on the link for "MinimalHtml.aspx", and the app will serve an HTML based xls file using the following in the Page Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=MinimalHtml.xls");
}
```

Depending on your browser and browser settings (my tests have been in Chrome), you may get Excel opened with a blank page. Regardless, you should get the file MinimalHtml.xls downloaded. It is a plain text file. You should find that this file will NOT open in Excel. However, if you zip the file, then extract it from zip, it WILL open.

I'm curious about what other file differences I'm missing when just doing an FC compare, but ultimately, I need to get the ASP.Net application corrected to serve the HTML version of the Excel file correctly. Interestingly, if I create an XML version of the spreadsheet, it downloads/opens fine. That is what the "MinimalXml.aspx" link does.

Can anyone help with either 1) how to figure out what is different about the two files; or 2) what must change in the ASP.Net application to get it to serve the file correctly?

Comment: Unless I've missed it (it's quite a lot of text here), you've failed to tell us *what happens* when you do try to open the second file? Do you get an error? If so, what does it say? If not, what *does* happen?

Comment: What does "this file will NOT open in Excel mean"? Is there an error displayed in Excel? A difference that comes immediately to my mind is the MOTW (mark of the Web) which gets attached to files downloaded from the internet. Depending on the zipping tool you use this mark gets also attached (or not) to a file when you unzip it from a zip package that has a MOTW. The MOTW is stored in an NTFS alternate data stream. You can remove this mark by opening the file properties and selecting *Unblock* (or by using Sysinternals' `streams -d <filename>` command).

Comment: Damien: Thanks very much for the request for clarification, I realize I was indeed not clear on what is the specific problem when attempting to open in Excel. What happens is that the Excel app itself opens, but with an empty, blank screen. The window title is simply "Excel". Dirk: Thanks, this "MOTW" sounds like a good possibility, I will investigate. Unfortunately, if that is indeed the problem, then it would seem to me there is nothing I can on the server to mitigate.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem might be a Microsoft security patch.  See this article:
[Infoworld article](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3098898/microsoft-windows/excel-refusing-to-open-files-blame-the-kb-3115322-3115262-security-updates.html)

When you open the file directly, the patch causes the issue which results in a blank page because the file contents is HTML not Excel.  When you download the file in a Zip file and unzip it, it is deemed safe and opens correctly.

Comment: I am seeing this issue only with Chrome, as well.  Also, I think Dirk's answer is at least partially correct because the MOTW explains the different behavior with opening the Excel file directly versus after extracting from a zip file.